# Support for embedded languages

Tags: filetype

Vim supports syntax highlighting for embedded languages or fenced code in markdown ([`:h :syn-include`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-include)).

However, you usually want that other vim settings and mappings are adjusted for embedded languages as well. These are for example

- load/unload ftplugins containing settings for example for

  - `b:match_words` used by matchit's `%`
  - `commentstring` (e.g. for vim-commentary)
  - square bracket motions (e.g. done in `VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/[vim,ruby,python,...].vim`)
- folds (`foldmethod` or `foldexpr`)
- indentation scripts in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/<language>.vim` (`indentexpr`)
- formatting (`formatprg` or dedicated plugins autoformat, neoformat)
- 'intellisense' completion (`omnifunc` or dedicated plugins ycm, deoplete, ncm2)
- linting (run compiler for code region or dedicated plugins ale, neomake or syntastic)
- ft snippets (ultisnips or snipmate)
- ...

#### Plugins

I know which are dedicated to this or have builtin support are

- [vim-context-commentstring](https://github.com/suy/vim-context-commentstring) (defines autocmd for the event `CursorMoved` and uses the current syntax group to adjust the `commentstring`)
- [nvim-ts-context-commentstring](https://github.com/JoosepAlviste/nvim-ts-context-commentstring) Neovim treesitter plugin for setting the commentstring based on the cursor location in a file.
- [tcomment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) (see `g:tcomment#filetype#guess`)
- ncm2 subscopes, e.g. https://github.com/ncm2/ncm2-markdown-subscope
- [context_filetype.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/context_filetype.vim), e.g. for deoplete

#### Relevant Tools

- universal ctags can use several parsers for one file, https://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/running-multi-parsers.html

It is one thing to adjust a single setting as done by https://github.com/suy/vim-context-commentstring but I miss support for the adjustments done in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin` and the `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/`.

Afaik, this is something which vim does not really cover. For example, I use the plugin SimpylFold which defines folds for python as I want it and vimtex for LaTeX files. However, I would not know if vim can combine this for a single latex file using pythontex.

I am not familiar with other editors and their solutions for this. A quick search revealed for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_embedded-languages) that vscode supports out of the box adjusted syntax highlighting and commenting.

Did I miss something in vim itself supporting loading/unloading ftplugin/indent or do you occasionally change the filetype by yourself?

Today many tasks (e.g. autocompletion, linting, snippets, formatting) are provided by dedicated plugins: Which of the major plugins i.e. ycm, deoplete, ale, syntastic, tagbar, ultisnips, snipmate, autoformat and neoformat support this?

Comment: For syntax there is [SyntaxRange](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-SyntaxRange).  If you expect a generic solution that works out of the box with _any_ template and / or embedded languages, you're chasing the pie in the sky.  It's a hard problem, that can be solved (given enough effort) for _particular_ languages.  Solving it generically is not possible.

Comment: SyntaxRange was not what I was looking for. vimtex already does this automatically for latex environments which contain different languages (python, lua, gnuplot, graphviz, asymptote, minted-languages). I would expect the same from other ftplugins which can contain embedded languages, e.g. html/css/javascript. But there is another plugin mentioned: [OnSyntaxChange](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085). So thanks for pointing me into this direction. I certainly agree that a generic solution is not feasible. I was interested in the experience of others and their take on this.

Comment: I thought the recommended way to source several files was to use a "combined" filetype, separated by `.`, e.g. `:set ft=php.sql` (just a silly example, as I don't know if those actually work)