# In PHP files, how can I auto close HTML tag pairs and indent the new line?

Tags: indentation

I have been a Vim user for several years now and I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue. There have been a lot of questions on the internet that try to address it, but none of the solutions I found work properly. When I'm doing WordPress development I need to mix in HTML into my template files. What I *ideally* want is for [Vim Closetag](https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag) to function in PHP files the same way it does in HTML files.

What I get is this:

Type: `<table>>`
Returns:

```
<table>
|
</table>
```

This gets even more annoying when dealing with inserting these tags in an already indented line.

What I want is:

```
<table>
   |
</table>
```

I have tried these settings with no luck.

```
let g:closetag_filenames = '*.html,*.xhtml,*.phtml,*.php'
let g:closetag_filetypes = 'html,xhtml,phtml,php'
```

A "solution" I found is setting `ft` to either `phtml` or `html`, but that then stops ALE's linting and fixing.

Does anyone have a viable solution for this? It's been driving me absolutely nuts and I can't figure out a good solution.

Comment: have you tried any combination of `set autoindent`, `set smartindent`, or `set cindent`?

Comment: @Mass I have, I haven't had a combination that works. I feel like this is a problem that's been solved before but I can't quite get it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have answer for you. But you should keep in mind that only one indentation script [`$VIMRUNTIME/indent/php.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/indent/php.vim) or [`$VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/indent/html.vim) will be sourced. I think your question might be related to https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/support-for-embedded-languages.

Comment: Some possibly related links: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Better_indent_support_for_php_with_html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459478/correct-indentation-of-html-and-php-using-vim,