# How to comment html in php file in vim?

Tags: neovim, comments, filetype-php, plugin-vim-commentary

I use this plugin for comments.

```
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
```

And when I comment html code in php I get

```
/* <div class="our-photos"> */
/*  <h2 class="our-photos__main-title"><?php echo $main_title; ?></h2> */
/*  <?php slider_component($our_photos, 'our_photos', false, false); ?> */
/* </div> */
```

But I want to get this

```
<!--<div class="our-photos">-->
<!--<h2 class="our-photos__main-title"><?php //echo $main_title; ?></h2>-->
<!--<?php //slider_component($our_photos, 'our_photos', false, false); ?>-->
<!--</div>-->
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the filetype of your file``:set ft?``. Could you also tell us what is commentstring of your file ``:set commentstring?``?

Comment: You could also be interested to this answer [Support for embedded languages](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/support-for-embedded-languages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your file type is `php` and your commentstring is `/*%s*/` which is reasonable for php files.

To solve your problem you could temporarily change commentstring to`<!--%s-->`:

```
set commentstring='<!--%s-->'
```

or set the filetype to `html`

```
set ft=html
```

If you want to do that forever for php file you could add the following command:

```
setlocal commentstring='<!--%s-->'
```

To the `vimfiles/after/ftplugin/php.vim` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved.

Comment: You are welcome ;-)

Comment: Sorry, i just set filetype from command mode, but where is vimfiles/after/ftplugin/php.vim to do forever for php files? 
I cant find vimfiles directory in my system, ubuntu.
Thanks.

Comment: By ``vimfiles`` I mean ``~/vimfiles`` if it doesn't exist you can create it.

Comment: Don't work for me, same after reboot the system. 
https://i.imgur.com/TEjrOOv.png

I am using neovim 7.0

Comment: For Neovim the place to look is: ``~/.config/nvim/after/php.vim`` or if defined: ``$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/after/php.vim``

Comment: Don't work))
https://i.imgur.com/tNhT9mh.png

Comment: In order to better understand the situation could you: Run the ``:scriptnames`` command (it will list the scripts that are run by Neovim). I'm also interested that you run the ``:set ft?`` command after loaded your ``.php`` file to verify that the its type is ``php`` and that you do another run of ``:scriptnames`` to verify what has been ran after the``.php`` has been loaded.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/atbaK1l.png

Comment: `:set ft?` - filetype=php

And :scriptnames result

https://i.imgur.com/nq4OyrE.png

Comment: Thanks. It look to me that your nvim instance refers to ``~/nvim-coc``. I would try to change the file ``~/nvim-coc/after/php.vim``. But I don't see in your screen short the last part of the output of ``:scriptnames``. You can use the command:  ``redir @* | scriptnames | redir END`` to move the entire result in the clipboard.